# How to pass param as an object with React-Navigation deep linking?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, react-navigation, deep-linking

I use React-Navigation deep linking to get params from an Url but I would like to pass these params to an object. Now I do this :

```
prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl('/'), 'https://test.app', 'https://*.test.app'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      App: {
        screens: {
          Chat: {
            path: 'chat/:firstName/:lastName/:birthdate',
            parse: {
              firstName: (firstName: string) => decodeURIComponent(firstName),
              lastName: (lastName: string) => decodeURIComponent(lastName),
              birthdate: (birthdate: string) => decodeURIComponent(birthdate),
            },
          },
```

This is the result :

```
 const { firstName, lastName, birthdate} = route.params
```

And what I need is an object with inside firstName, lastName, birthdate :

```
const { userObject } = route.params
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [getStateFromPath](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links#advanced-cases) to configure the params however you like.

Something like this should work. Note: I haven't tested with nested screens. You may need to modify this slightly to handle the nested screens.

```js
import { getStateFromPath } from '@react-navigation/native';

const linking = {
  prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl('/'), 'https://test.app', 'https://*.test.app'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      App: {
        screens: {
          Chat: {
            path: 'chat/:firstName/:lastName/:birthdate',
            parse: {
              firstName: (firstName: string) => decodeURIComponent(firstName),
              lastName: (lastName: string) => decodeURIComponent(lastName),
              birthdate: (birthdate: string) => decodeURIComponent(birthdate),
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  getStateFromPath: (path, options) => {
    const state = getStateFromPath(path, options);
    const newState = {
      ...state,
      routes: state.routes.map(route => {
        if (route.name === 'Chat') {
          // modify your params however you like here!
          return {
            ...route,
            params: { userObject: route.params }
          }
        } else {
          return route
        }
      }),
    };
    return newState;
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you mention in which file do I've to update this code?

Comment: @AyushKatuwal The linking variable which is created in that code block above is passed into NavigationContainer as a prop.

So, technically it can go anywhere, but it will probably be best in your entry point to your app - App.jsx, or index.js or something like that.

I recommend checking out these two pages of the docs which explain it: [Deep Linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking) and [Configuring Links](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links)

Comment: Wow thank you, I got that :-)

Comment: I try this solution but I got state as undefine so routes: state.routes.map is not working, is there any support as I try this command >> npx uri-scheme open "exp://myIP/--/chat/testname" --android   @Tom S

Comment: @fatmamahmoud Does `path` exist before you pass it to `getStateForPath`?

Comment: I got the error I has image_url on the params and try to to put the link in between "", but problem not solved

Comment: Sorry @fatmamahmoud I don't understand your issue. Maybe you should start a new StackOverflow question with more details.